# Stack cannot push due to : String cannot be converted to char

Tags: java, stack, push

```
import java.util.*;

public class plates2{
    private static Scanner in;
    private static Stack platestack = new Stack();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        add();
    }

    public static void add()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter plate: ");
        String pl = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Plate added! ");

        platestack.push(pl);
    }
}
```

So I cannot compile the code and gave me this error.

error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to char
                    platestack.push(pl);

Can someone please point out what's wrong? I want to push a string to the stack.

Comment: Your code works fine for me

Comment: your code is working fine! :)

Comment: When I compile this class (using Java 8), I do not get any error messages.  I only get a warning about unsafe / unchecked operations.

Comment: Really? I have jdk1.8.0_66 and got the error.

Comment: Yes really.  I am not joking.

Comment: I am able to add the string to stack 1.8_60

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I compile this class (using Java 8), I do not get any error messages. I only get a warning about unsafe / unchecked operations.

But then you said you got this!

> error: cannot infer type arguments for Stack private static Stack platestack = new Stack<>(); reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class Stack

**>>Light-bulb moment<<**

But `java.util.Stack` is a generic class.  It has been since Java 5, when generics were introduced.

You must have defined your own `Stack` class, and you must be using it instead of the standard `java.util.Stack`.  If you did that, *and* you defined the `Stack.push` operation to take (only) a `char` argument, then *that* would explain this compilation error.  And it would *also* explain nobody else is seeing the compilation error.

Comment: >>Light-bulb moment<<

Thanks. I have a file with the same classname with Stack. That caused the error. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining your `Stack` to use strings with generics:

```
private static Stack<String> platestack = new Stack<>();
```

Comment: error: cannot infer type arguments for Stack private static Stack<String> platestack = new Stack<>();
reason: cannot use '<>' with non-generic class Stack

Comment: What version of Java are you running?

Comment: I have a kit jdk1.8.0_66